# Customizing function in a standard js file of Fiori app

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have requirement to customize a js file (statushandler.js) in a standard Fiori application (PMRoffers).
I have read through the documentation and blogs for the same, and followed the below approach

1. Copied the statushandler.js file into my extension project with the path similar to standard apps folder structure
2. made reference to the extended file into the controllers calling the same, under sap.ui.define([])

Tried to launch the extended app, I can see in the chrome debugger, the custom file is loading, however the functions within that is not getting called.
Not sure if any  step is being missed , need your expert advice.

Thanks.
Regards,
Naresh.D

Answer (score 1):

JS dosen't work like that. There is no magic code which tells the standard app that there is now another file.

BUT, first of all; i really can't recommend what im describing now. You should never use anything else then the provided extension points by SAP. If there is no point don't do it.

Nevertheless, documentation points out you can just copy the original app and change whatever you want. If you want to change the 'statushandler.js' with a 'MyStatushandler.js' you muss tell the caller controller this. So change in your copy.application also the caller part.